# Как реализовать отрисовку произвольных регионов фигуры?

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование

Не знаю как подойти к его реализации.
Хочу реализовать карту с которой можно будет взаимодействовать.(На web-странице.)

1) При наведении на область 1, взаимодействовать с областью 1.

2) При наведении на область 2, взаимодействовать с областью 2.

3) и т.д.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поразмыслив, я пришел к тому, что карта будет состоять из набора векторных изображений подогнанных друг к другу. И тут встал вопрос: как подогнать элементы идеально друг к другу, без наплывов и зазоров?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а откуда возьмутся наплывы и зазоры, если у элементов будут четкие соответствующие границы?

Comment: @lexxl он видимо спрашивает про то, как их соединять. А это интересный вопрос.

Comment: Не пробовали с помощью svg рисовать? Там можно и id накидать и подсвечивать onhover

Comment: как соединять зависит от того, из чего будет состоять. я бы, наверное, попробовал отрисовать в SVG

Comment: Спасибо, попробую

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Могу предложить вариант.
В богом забытом редакторе под названием `DreamWeaver` есть инструмент под названием `Polygonal hotspot tool` которым можно обвести картинку любой сложности. Далее сохранить это дело как `web` страницу, в результате чего получить `html` с координатами.

Далее просто берем эти самые координаты и переносим в `svg`.

Всё!

100% для создания координат есть еще инструменты. Но алгоритм прост: берем картинку, инструмент, обводим, получаем координаты, перекидываем координаты в `svg`

```js
var allStates = $("svg.us > *");

allStates.on("mouseover", function() {
  
  allStates.removeClass("on");
  $(this).addClass("on");
  
});
```

```css
.on {
  fill: pink;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 2;
}

body {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0-alpha1.js"></script>
<svg class="us" viewBox="0 0 542.460022 416.2406921">
<polygon points="118.3980026,106.9002991 110.3418045,168.6753082 157.9750977,174.214798 161.7349091,125.6010056 
 142.8388977,123.868103 144.5113068,110.4550018 "/>
<polygon points="146.2432098,121.6489029 210.8184052,125.7578049 212.1533966,77.5830002 151.0596008,73.3442001 "/>
<polygon points="229.7998047,129.7543945 164.5996094,125.3955002 161.0401001,174.6992035 230.3609009,177.3343964 "/>
<polygon points="55.7056084,134.4550018 98.2920074,191.4458008 98.8799057,179.2167969 103.4073029,179.0473022 
 105.9097061,180.6987 115.7608032,106.3012009 63.3013077,97.6298065 "/>
<polygon points="88.5674057,99.396904 94.2715073,74.7723999 91.0850067,73.4975052 92.6436081,68.5565948 101.1392059,55.7612038 
 97.8096008,50.654705 82.3438034,47.3974037 66.8662109,50.690403 60.2105064,49.8935051 58.0430069,47.8823051 
 52.1490059,48.8012047 47.5435066,46.8813057 46.5738068,39.5947037 38.5381088,39.1972046 28.154808,69.2285004 
 22.8433075,76.4013062 23.5572071,86.1391068 "/>
<polygon points="214.4365997,64.0727005 214.2847137,101.914505 262.3935852,101.5078049 267.7217102,104.0975952 
 275.3233032,102.2441025 280.1162109,104.505806 279.4786072,94.3403015 281.1679993,92.8813019 280.3847961,71.9878006 
 276.0635071,68.3139038 277.539093,63.6269035 "/>
<polygon points="278.9628906,61.9282036 271.4038086,25.4975052 214.7373047,25.526804 213.9911957,61.4735947 "/>
<polygon points="213.9595032,125.8143997 232.5702972,126.7851028 232.8222961,140.6259003 293.8349915,140.2597046 
 288.4707031,129.5731964 286.4169922,121.2807007 281.7421875,108.2050018 274.9825134,104.6211014 267.7603149,107.3330002 
 261.3486938,103.738205 214.2847137,104.1049042 "/>
<polygon points="232.4864044,143.1777039 232.7071075,176.9965057 303.2138977,176.5243988 301.468811,150.7070007 
 295.6875,145.3451996 296.6152954,142.1717987 "/>
<polygon points="161.5367126,241.3847046 176.8858032,241.5077972 177.4911957,239.0449066 216.2754059,241.0791016 
 217.7217102,179.7259979 161.1381989,177.3110046 154.4067993,246.5350952 160.3399048,246.6600952 "/>
<polygon points="50.2774086,45.3837051 58.6221085,44.7225914 62.2349091,48.0742035 81.6582108,45.2548027 98.5035019,48.111805 
 104.5391006,13.7099047 87.3057098,9.8222046 56.3995056,4.0048051 57.988308,9.1762047 57.2491074,22.0087051 
 56.3550072,21.4433041 53.3482056,15.6269045 44.885807,13.1543045 38.7701073,8.1528053 39.7183075,24.158205 
 42.6084061,26.8398037 39.539608,28.6987038 42.7520065,30.6704044 38.9737053,32.2070045 38.3814087,35.0185051 
 47.914608,38.1494026 "/>
<polygon points="114.0791016,35.6713028 120.3643036,45.200592 124.5826035,46.0888023 119.9195023,61.2583046 
 126.6211014,61.0839043 132.3462067,76.4858017 147.1161957,77.5781021 148.9707031,71.2319031 211.7828064,74.557106 
 213.0782013,25.3378048 113.6973038,16.1572056 111.7154007,28.4365044 "/>
<polygon points="132.093811,246.6717987 151.3648071,246.8983917 158.3457031,177.2416992 109.7364044,171.1395874 
 107.3677063,182.387207 101.7310028,180.8549042 99.5059052,195.9320984 103.3013077,204.1595917 99.2271042,207.1035004 
 95.0909042,217.7187042 97.6846008,221.8065948 93.9844055,225.4325867 "/>
<polygon points="103.6529007,55.2421036 93.7925034,71.3037033 96.6563034,73.2890015 90.922905,99.5600052 
 144.5879059,107.8368988 147.5424957,79.6547012 130.0292969,78.8945007 125.2085037,62.804203 117.8692017,62.3813019 
 121.0953064,48.5620041 112.0679016,37.8388062 111.189003,32.9902039 109.4878006,30.5649052 109.2520065,27.8320045 
 111.1939011,14.5068045 106.6285019,13.6318045 101.0064011,49.7612038 "/>
<path d="M19.5498066,128.1356964l2.8945999,12.0967102l4.3227005,3.675293l-0.0096989,9.0664062l5.1097984,6.0858917
 l-3.3514996,3.6138l10.5067997,19.8310089c0,0-2.1894989,6.7079926-1.1450005,6.6694946
 c1.0449028-0.0395966,11.6743011,4.4438019,11.6743011,4.4438019l0.5043983,4.1660004l7.7397003,1.8027954l-0.5135994,4.902298
 l10.7728996,8.3144989l0.2865982,7.6611023l24.8423004,2.2080078l0.1787033-4.5400085l2.7167969-11.2617035l4.0484009-3.6391907
 l-2.9297028-3.7250977l-0.8788986-4.8486023l-43.7089958-59.0415039l7.1820984-38.5527954l-35.3363991-7.7441025
 l-0.4429016,9.0067902l-6.9862995,8.9805145l3.4990005,9.6342926L19.5498066,128.1356964z"/>
<polygon points="281.9873047,105.4047012 292.3681946,131.1703949 328.8799133,128.4095917 332.467804,131.0644073 
 337.3526001,121.8153992 334.4101868,117.7406998 342.3017883,114.3065948 343.8203125,108.3203049 336.9317017,101.2548065 
 332.726593,100.7153015 330.967804,91.0165939 283.0020142,95.2544022 "/>
<polygon points="355.0126953,183.8695984 359.8526001,173.2812042 354.8349915,169.6318054 355.0019836,164.7440948 
 344.319397,158.8670959 346.7792969,150.0565948 339.7246094,147.8807983 340.3154907,145.0673065 332.7286072,138.0283051 
 331.1524048,133.2060089 328.2626953,130.5249023 292.8067017,133.5957031 293.5683899,135.3099976 297.9433899,140.3773956 
 301.4130859,139.9002991 301.5039062,142.335907 298.1123047,144.9047089 303.5185852,149.5843964 306.8339844,182.2407074 
 351.0087891,179.1909027 351.7763977,181.2440948 350.4327087,183.7792969 "/>
<polygon points="414.944397,182.3769073 421.1347961,180.0527039 428.1865845,172.8144073 432.2998047,170.9154968 
 434.3995056,166.6419983 372.4815063,175.2480011 371.8897095,178.0615082 359.4179993,180.2714081 353.7294922,191.5019073 
 356.1495056,195.3895874 353.1455078,198.987793 412.780304,189.7812042 411.6054993,186.3368988 414.3526001,185.1878967 "/>
<!-- <polygon points="320.2774048,252.527298 316.1474915,244.6620941 313.9667969,242.3027039 313.5712891,222.4414062 
  301.5751953,218.7050018 294.2745056,219.3271027 287.7227173,221.3164062 283.1054993,219.0487976 279.3135071,220.2362976 
  275.4429016,219.335907 272.3486938,220.4980011 270.1542969,217.7890015 257.8876953,216.1562042 257.7837219,213.3710938 
  249.6958008,211.5800018 249.144104,187.539505 220.2984009,187.9985046 218.0186005,243.5312042 180.949295,240.7342987 
  191.0288086,255.9745941 197.4145966,258.8739929 197.6289062,258.9472046 200.2823029,270.273407 214.990799,281.2313843 
  221.9638977,271.9023132 230.4893036,270.2626953 234.8623047,271.7684937 238.8516083,273.0116882 253.6138,297.5693054 
  258.5405884,298.7782898 258.5185852,307.4979858 263.2929993,313.9453125 282.7070923,320.1922913 280.7022095,303.8778992 
  282.2344055,298.2402039 279.3174133,294.8623047 284.2197876,295.3778992 282.6700134,291.250885 287.9317017,292.0995789 
  286.8106079,288.023407 289.2471008,289.9588928 291.2969055,288.835907 289.4512024,286.1131897 291.4755859,284.2948914 
  296.7784119,286.188385 307.5567017,276.0195007 305.2979126,271.5722046 309.7471008,269.313385 311.6308899,273.0780945 
  316.7373047,269.7479858 "/> -->
<polygon points="259.4595032,211.5644073 259.9121094,214.3368988 271.4560852,215.2998047 273.3017883,218.0204926 
 277.4404907,216.8182983 279.2344055,218.1473999 284.0712891,216.9199066 288.3145142,218.5039062 300.8125,216.9902039 
 308.8760071,218.0838928 304.8623047,185.4530945 302.8731079,178.9017944 220.5337067,180.3173065 220.3814087,185.5545959 
 251.5166016,185.7075043 252.4165039,209.7362976 "/>
<polygon points="347.453186,186.648407 349.3203125,180.6499023 307.2998047,185.3612976 311.2597961,216.598587 315.1308899,217.5 
 315.8037109,226.1932983 344.6817017,224.4140015 342.9755859,216.1083984 349.7149048,200.512207 352.3037109,195.184494 
 350.4072876,191.0708008 353.9306946,186.3939972 "/>
<polygon points="368.0947876,262.9432983 358.2657166,261.218689 357.4522095,258.1112976 365.5126953,259.2030945 
 362.9042969,254.7695007 361.0078125,250.6562042 340.8222961,251.7586975 340.9101868,244.7812042 346.4912109,235.5057983 
 344.8554993,226.9237976 316.5,228.6835938 316.3505859,240.8193054 322.6767883,251.3925018 319.8320923,268.585907 
 326.4501953,268.3377991 338.0322876,270.3465881 339.6299133,266.4491882 348.8135071,269.5927124 351.4092102,273.680603 
 355.6133118,274.219696 359.0058899,271.6532898 360.4883118,274.0379944 363.2099915,272.1922913 360.9638977,268.0917969 
 373.7089844,273.1953125 374.6368103,270.0213928 365.7998047,266.8652039 "/>
<polygon points="372.1435852,198.887207 352.1416016,202.5135956 345.3370056,216.3690948 348.8652954,233.7597046 
 342.9229126,249.675705 361.6885071,247.9266968 368.3486938,258.1385803 372.7099915,255.8827972 377.4306946,256.2294922 
 373.631897,238.5858917 "/>
<polygon points="412.9541016,241.0370941 411.3447876,232.9891968 411.1103821,226.7207031 411.2539062,223.5771027 
 408.5743103,221.8465881 398.6582031,194.4945984 376.3135071,198.469696 376.4746094,237.6952972 379.2294922,255.3768921 
 380.7861938,255.0575867 382.2070923,251.0820007 385.2666016,255.9355011 388.8926086,255.0155945 388.726593,250.5760956 
 385.194397,247.0467987 "/>
<polygon points="401.5118103,193.8647003 411.6592102,220.4237976 413.9151001,224.7850952 412.5048828,229.023407 
 413.7548828,234.4687042 415.5947876,241.723587 416.9902954,244.0252991 443.5517883,240.9375 446.7929993,243.6932983 
 446.2969055,237.4355011 451.530304,237.5009003 454.8613892,221.6835938 428.5,195.2080078 421.6416016,193.634201 
 423.3037109,189.1253967 "/>
<polygon points="465.0644836,263.6698914 467.9277954,263.3016968 460.8243103,255.1992035 453.195282,240.0536957 
 448.4844055,239.9687042 447.6542969,245.7539062 443.6289062,243.027298 416.2842102,246.1434937 413.5751953,243.6298065 
 389.4228821,248.1952972 392.5010071,253.5722046 393.9892883,251.4248047 395.6152954,252.9335938 398.7197876,252.032196 
 400.5,250.6582031 403.3916016,251.0722046 403.1885071,252.6493988 409.2452087,253.7303925 414.6835938,259.2802124 
 423.6885071,255.2812042 424.8769836,252.0995941 431.2227173,253.9530945 439.8847961,261.7362976 442.5048828,261.9002991 
 445.6036072,267.7987976 444.9589844,278.5467834 449.069397,276.5614929 450.203186,278.8729858 447.2158813,282.9090881 
 453.9990845,289.4541016 455.7490845,287.2967834 456.7187805,292.2304077 459.3692017,293.1766968 461.6933899,299.3662109 
 465.9024048,299.993103 471.0596008,305.032196 470.3447876,306.8885803 472.2022095,307.6044922 478.7861938,305.2127991 
 478.7217102,307.0975952 474.6904907,311.1727905 479.7666016,307.0595093 479.6103821,302.8807983 479.4628906,302.9881897 
 479.757782,285.875 "/>
<polygon points="455.7988892,218.7704926 457.9931946,214.5039062 465.8447876,207.6708984 469.1123047,204.1488953 
 468.9755859,200.4920959 473.9062805,192.4613953 460.2637024,184.3417969 447.8154907,187.1615906 446.6240845,183.2826996 
 432.0469055,185.1362 425.6728821,189.559494 424.726593,192.210907 429.7276001,193.0693054 "/>
<polygon points="485.7911072,160.6313019 494.2637024,156.3905945 492.2421875,153.7528992 437.078186,165.8554077 
 433.1533813,172.8022003 429.6347961,175.5825043 422.5664062,182.3852081 416.2978821,183.634201 415.1083984,186.8168945 
 413.8417969,187.9105988 414.9356079,189.1772003 426.6005859,186.3867035 432.4609985,182.2440948 447.0673828,181.1743011 
 450.5801086,184.1805878 460.6972961,181.9712067 476.226593,191.589798 480.9082031,190.8915863 481.0234985,186.9638062 
 485.953186,178.9331055 493.9717102,176.5404968 493.8437805,173.1450043 486.8710938,175.4985046 490.7001953,173.0014038 
 490.8536072,170.1190948 486.3554993,168.7176971 495.1865845,167.0794983 497.0606079,161.2548065 485.0469055,161.7055054 "/>
<path d="M367.7745056,110.1264038l-3.851593-5.0868988c0,0,0.094696-4.4496994-0.679718-4.1592026
 c-0.773407,0.2906036-21.6191101,2.3794022-21.6191101,2.3794022l4.1045227,4.8154984l-2.3291016,7.6713028l-6.1700134,2.8471985
 l1.9649048,3.5878906l-5.3447876,10.9233093l8.2460938,10.6763l-0.1532898,2.8827972l7.1591797,2.6083984l-2.2987976,8.4561005
 l9.6073914,5.1318054l0.4862976,5.9975891l3.2139282,0.9589996l1.4989929-1.8872986l4.7685852,1.6524048l-0.9111938-3.3661957
 l3.5888977-1.9654083l-0.1308899-9.4428101l3.8760071-8.2529907l-3.2617188-3.2782898L371.25,140.0737L367.7745056,110.1264038z"/>
<polygon points="374.5361938,109.0888062 370.4346008,111.3348999 373.3486938,140.2568054 371.8604126,142.4051971 
 375.0820923,144.6381073 370.7529907,154.7387085 371.7120056,159.4105988 376.375,158.1898956 378.7637024,159.1468964 
 380.4853821,156.2050018 383.4161072,157.664505 385.6103821,153.3979034 390.6513977,154.2875977 394.4483032,144.9589081 
 397.0596008,144.8612976 399.3526001,143.2060089 392.780304,106.346199 "/>
<path d="M281.2363892,62.1045036l-3.1806946,5.8729973l4.2958984,2.9775009l1.6054993,21.910202l45.6473999-3.278801
 l-1.4227905-3.0855026l-13.3916016-8.391098l-1.4160156-9.8856964l-1.7148743-3.8583984l1.9325867-4.2573051
 c0,0,5.156311-2.0234985,4.381897-1.7333984c-0.7734985,0.2905006-1.2783813-6.2290001-1.2783813-6.2290001l20.4404907-19.8584099
 l-9.1992188-1.2246895l-4.8066711,4.3647995l-5.6513062-4.2343998l-2.5518188,1.6646023l-4.1044922-4.8159027l-4.1885071-0.1044998
 l-1.7098999,3.2026005l-10.0908813-4.0683994c0,0-1.8515015-7.5151119-2.625-7.2245998
 c-0.7744141,0.2905998-1.5761108-0.2026005-2.0693054,0.6000996c-0.4931946,0.8036995,0.4267883,4.4307003,0.4267883,4.4307003
 l-16.4448853,0.8773994L281.2363892,62.1045036z"/>
<path d="M317.0712891,76.1938019l13.9638977,9.6772995l3.3809204,13.4736023l4.7207031,0.346199l24.7929077-1.4512024
 l-2.3437195-6.7123947l1.7539062-16.0195007l3.0137024-10.314003l-7.9961243,9.9771042l1.5546265-7.3819046l-4.5312195-9.2455978
 l-18.477478-4.5390015l-5.3223267-2.4160995L328.4375,51.4443054c0,0,2.4453125-4.5371017,1.6729126-4.2471008
 c-0.7744141,0.2905998-10.7842102,5.3736-10.7842102,5.3736l0.5253906,7.0419998l-5.8310852,4.9257011L317.0712891,76.1938019z"/>
<g>
 <polygon points="338.9638977,53.1430054 355.7851868,55.3901024 359.6181946,59.9541054 361.4306946,66.4248047 
  364.7149048,56.3628044 377.8876953,51.9467049 385.5019836,52.708004 385.9462891,50.5985947 394.3037109,50.2855911 
  387.3067017,45.0555916 381.3399048,46.3252029 380.1484985,42.4462051 367.5654907,48.6718025 361.0361938,48.9160042 
  356.1679993,44.6523056 350.2099915,46.1831055 350.3544922,43.0390053 355.3721008,37.3588028 352.4697876,36.6825943 
  336.2626953,50.8901024  "/>
 <polygon points="382.5537109,57.7875938 383.1728821,60.3798027 380.6298828,62.3055916 381.6094055,67.5 379.5205078,67.5781021 
  379.1611938,64.9760056 374.1524048,70.9179001 373.6817017,79.3045959 373.9072876,85.3115005 378.2060852,95.3510056 
  375.8027954,106.9813995 406.2431946,102.7031021 408.0185852,95.2807007 410.1846008,90.2304001 412.8056946,90.3940048 
  412.6103821,85.1704025 407.217804,73.8642044 402.5654907,75.3462067 398.5810852,80.7260056 396.3554993,77.1473999 
  401.1524048,72.5223999 400.0449829,63.9325943 398.5537109,59.0190048 384.554718,55.3588028  "/>
</g>
<polygon points="395.9092102,106.0981064 401.1308899,137.2875977 406.5214844,141.532196 415.5253906,142.0771027 
 418.281311,138.835907 421.9844055,142.391098 424.3769836,139.9477081 424.5401001,133.7953949 427.8378906,134.5874023 
 428.5361938,128.8070984 431.8984985,127.7655945 434.217804,123.363205 434.8027954,111.0488052 431.8740845,96.7412033 
 422.2431946,104.948204 418.3349915,105.3563995 415.0478821,108.3563995 406.0010071,104.2490005 "/>
<polygon points="494.2315063,57.7900047 496.4317017,67.6464005 501.6074829,66.1450043 499.8183899,46.334404 
 503.5899048,42.2700043 501.8467102,37.627903 488.4219055,42.3149033 492.4042969,57.8584023 "/>
<polygon points="497.6132812,92.1870041 497.9981079,88.5112 495.2666016,78.413002 494.914093,69.010704 492.7431946,59.9384041 
 490.3935852,60.0258026 485.5585938,42.6840057 474.3867798,44.6718025 463.9551086,59.4472046 466.3642883,60.925705 
 466.8115845,65.8784027 460.7392883,71.3369064 457.9658813,73.0835037 452.1495056,72.443306 442.5937805,75.6781998 
 445.6914062,81.5775909 439.2138977,90.1893997 440.3085938,92.2080002 480.5361938,83.1499023 485.1708984,88.2070007 
 496.5870056,92.7485046 497.2763977,97.1694031 504.7138977,93.2290039 513.0878906,86.3768997 502.2851868,91.2275009 "/>
<polygon points="502.4404907,46.4975052 503.6767883,65.5444031 513.0302734,63.8862038 516.2393188,58.7968025 
 505.8399048,32.5087051 504.2919922,33.0898056 503.9462891,37.8105049 505.1376953,41.6889038 "/>
<polygon points="542.460022,25.6450043 539.7315063,22.6088047 536.8779907,23.2387047 535.1542969,19.1185932 531.1875,17.959404 
 526.1416016,1.9325927 521.8837891,-0.0004947 517.5615845,3.3003051 513.8164062,1.0864053 510.5224915,10.8867054 
 510.4863892,16.9038048 510.5380859,25.2714043 507.3867798,31.9277039 517.9697876,56.1162033 519.3427734,46.1264038 
 522.8222656,45.9961052 528.1503906,41.611805 528.2354126,36.9008026 532.1240845,35.9707031 531.694397,33.7778053 
 532.3067017,33.8715057 "/>
<polygon points="482.820282,111.6704025 485.0048828,108.9076996 487.1708984,109.153801 489.9306946,104.2768021 
 485.0498047,98.9345016 484.1094055,94.7851028 486.0429993,90.5283051 479.2988892,85.0268021 439.2041016,94.1460037 
 437.6865845,91.2929001 433.632782,95.5312042 440.0527954,122.033699 "/>
<polygon points="418.1279907,141.7182007 416.1065063,143.625 406.1719055,143.7353058 402.1368103,140.7480011 
 401.1611938,142.6152039 398.4248047,146.3793945 395.3008118,146.7577972 392.7227173,157.2182007 386.9385071,156.3885956 
 385.3233032,159.6860046 381.2911072,159.2153015 381.1269836,161.8368988 376.3858032,160.9682007 371.2784119,161.7807007 
 372.1699829,164.6244965 368.0791016,167.1318054 368.5058899,171.5619965 362.7402954,171.2548065 360.8955078,177.8623047 
 369.2138977,176.5048065 371.4570923,173.543396 415.6611938,166.657196 421.2901001,163.3081055 422.2471008,160.9179077 
 427.7774048,154.9575043 421.5253906,148.6528015 421.3692017,144.4741058 "/>
<path d="M436.9483032,155.398407l2.2909851,0.6122894l6.6338196-4.4331055l1.4862976-6.8560028l3.0137024-7.9593811
 l4.032196,0.5467987l0.7323914-5.3128967l1.9267883-0.9224091l2.9638977-2.9223938l1.0527039-5.0742035l4.8251953,1.3887024
 l0.8496094-1.9169998l-2.7236023-2.8623047l-3.1699829,1.0444031l-2.1748047,3.2089996l-2.9227905-1.3828049l-2.6885071,2.7153015
 l-3.3379211,3.9618988l-0.0643921-1.1611023l-0.9120789-6.4198914l-10.2579041,2.6610947l-1.835907-9.0088043l-0.4989929,9.9580002
 l-3.1328125,4.9444122l-2.4296875,0.1464996l-0.9717102,6.6615906l-3.3291016-0.3990021l-0.1835938,4.3666992l-1.6600952,3.0171051
 l-1.1700134,0.5756989c-0.5155945,0.1939087,0.492218,3.8179016,0.492218,3.8179016l10.6181946,8.8433075L436.9483032,155.398407z"
 />
<polygon points="451.6358032,161.1253967 491.2207031,151.9715881 490.414093,149.0379944 485.3897095,149.9228058 
 482.8437805,147.0541992 486.8789062,147.7743988 487.1748047,146.3690948 483.7901001,144.4033051 486.5361938,143.2543945 
 483.4776001,140.7539062 485.1026001,137.5541992 481.0010071,139.9194031 476.3164062,135.9100952 476.2315063,133.6464081 
 472.9238892,133.7705078 472.8574829,128.0731964 468.179718,123.3671036 467.4179993,126.4360046 462.1221008,125.3559036 
 462.0722961,128.6708984 456.8798828,133.5550995 455.6690063,138.4813995 451.6856079,139.1538086 448.9462891,145.1855011 
 448.8056946,150.7695007 441.851593,156.2098999 440.3897095,158.9642944 437.5537109,157.5991058 435.0263977,159.9604034 
 430.0234985,156.703598 424.6074829,161.0917969 424.1827087,163.7225952 420.101593,166.4911957 436.405304,164.1376953 "/>
<polygon points="497.8907166,78.6640015 499.7911072,87.4858017 499.0322876,90.4780045 504.8017883,86.2518997 
 513.7382812,82.778801 510.8399048,75.2143021 "/>

<path d="M486.664093,117.5746994c-0.2616882,0.0097046-1.3222961-3.8741074-1.3222961-3.8741074l0.6953125-2.3793869
 l-1.1903992-0.3476105l-0.9619141,2.2588043l5.3604126,14.6094055l4.8260803-0.9986038l-0.7987976-3.8926086
 C493.2724915,122.950592,486.9238892,117.5643997,486.664093,117.5746994z"/>

<g>
 <path d="M322.0401001,387.7411804c0,0-1.1758118,5.2275085-1.5673828,5.2275085
  c-0.3926086,0,1.3065796,6.4032898,1.3065796,6.4032898l1.9599915,0.9151001l3.2666016-2.875l2.6143188-0.2617798
  l1.8291016-2.0908203l-3.2666016-4.5741882L322.0401001,387.7411804z"/>
 <polygon points="314.069397,380.4237976 313.5458984,381.2070007 316.4208984,384.6054077 320.0801086,382.7752991 
  317.2051086,380.6845093  "/>
 <polygon points="307.1426086,379.6395874 311.8477173,380.1621094 312.5010071,378.8554077 308.4501953,378.0711975  "/>
 <polygon points="298.9101868,375.1961975 302.8301086,378.593689 304.5292969,376.7645874 301.5234985,373.4970093  "/>
 <polygon points="285.4501953,368.531189 284.9267883,370.0995789 287.5411072,371.7987976 289.631897,369.1845093 
  287.6719055,367.7470093  "/>
 <polygon points="309.6260071,381.3377991 310.9327087,383.2987976 312.3702087,381.9911804 311.3243103,381.0770874  "/>
 <polygon points="280.092804,371.9295959 281.2685852,372.5830078 282.8370056,370.7528992 282.0517883,370.0995789  "/>
</g>
<g>
 <polygon fill="none" points="118.7725067,349.8554077 119.2618027,350.1015015 119.0572052,349.8270874  "/>
 <path d="M196.3984985,373.8486023l-17.0375977-15.2227173l-6.2198029-3.063385l-0.8177948-2.4179993l-1.940506-1.5215149
  l-3.191391,2.8135071l-1.9116058,6.7246094l-1.2020874-0.7910156l-0.875-0.577179l-9.8130035-6.5664062l-0.8179016-2.1893921
  l-6.0220032,2.2489929l-1.7920074-0.8633118l-15.8714905-84.8690796l-7.7237015-3.9785156l-6.680603,3.4941101l-3.908699-2.7832031
  l-5.3920975,1.2645874l-4.4003983-3.0975952c0,0-10.8218002,0.4219055-10.0147018,0.2451172
  c0.8077011-0.1768188,0.1006012-3.4062195,0.1006012-3.4062195l-2.5429001-0.7958984L85.922905,259.75l-2.1939011-2.5332031
  l-3.9160004,2.2098999l0.5650024-2.8309937l-1.7084961-1.2333984l-4.3418045,3.743103l-5.2529984-0.0350952l-9.1585999,4.5419922
  l-2.8721008,3.4510803l-0.7455978,0.8946228l0.1254997,0.2792969l-1.8892021,3.5712891l-0.1455002,0.023407l-9.1791992,1.5137024
  l-2.0586014,4.5116882l7.429203,9.2030945l0.1313972,3.6943054l7.3276024,1.0830078l-1.6729012,5.0401001l3.9819984-0.3643188
  l2.7778015,1.6768188l-7.2588005,3.3652039c0,0-6.6732979-1.5-7.4530983-1.5830078
  c-0.7798004-0.0840149,0.6758003-3.8710938,0.6758003-3.8710938l-2.0235023-0.7412109l-4.8446999,1.0596008l-0.5093002,2.3105164
  l-2.2557983-1.0283203l-7.1724014,3.1777039l6.5454025,5.1669922l-2.7656021,1.281311l1.2094994,5.9111023l11.4071999,1.4804993
  l1.5693016,2.5332031l7.3115005-4.4776001l2.0620995,2.8486938l-3.517601,0.9393921l0.4682007,7.9356079l-1.7817001,1.9121094
  l-3.5551987-1.1679993l-4.6015015,3.7149048l-2.8969994-2.4121094l-3.9434013,2.4707031l0.6514015,3.75l-2.6815987,0.5018921
  l-6.0298023,7.242218l2.5912991,5.2704773l1.5596008,0.1660156l1.0776024,2.217804l-3.1641006,2.5536804l4.6816978,7.8583984
  l8.3891029-2.257782L48.0249062,362.75l-0.5443993,7.5643921l7.3778992-2.6298828l6.6387024,6.7538757l1.8540001-5.0594788
  l0.9389992,3.5174866l6.5424957-2.1932983l-3.0043945,5.9873047l-0.153801,1.4403992l-0.5327988,0.0635071l-1.0185013,4.6229858
  l-5.1494026,3.9179993l-0.256897,2.4082031l-14.2173004,7.6133118l-3.7220993,0.3916016l-7.1065025,5.0243835l0.7621994,2.7090149
  l4.3243027-1.1143188l4.3973999-4.2626953l0.6133003,1.6426086l8.1293983-2.2871094l2.2001991,1.5487976l6.0400009-4.875
  l-0.8456993-1.9295959L64.9200058,391.625l2.6268997,0.0174866l6.5596008-4.8193054l-1.857399-2.3007812l11.1723022-6.1679077
  l1.4277954-3.5283813l3.1635056-2.5527039l-4.1411057-3.0703125l0.4814987-2.0517883l5.9188995-6.2021179l6.3345032-10.1005859
  l5.0106964-2.6201172l2.3697052,0.2528992l-0.7168045,1.5010071l1.625,2.0126953l-4.1860962-0.1835938l-3.9432983,2.4707031
  l-1.8052063,9.532196l2.858902,0.304718l-1.0292969,2.2567749l-2.1900024,0.8174133l0.5849991,1.9024048l11.3662033-7.9864197
  l4.5565948-0.8280945l1.2789001-4.5957031l-2.6093979-2.6434937l1.3598022-3.2842102l1.5439987,0.703125l4.8026962-0.4775085
  l0.5166016,2.3592834l2.2968979-0.8583984l1.7505035,2.3409119l9.0781021,3.5975952l9.782196-0.5332031l1.9579926-1.1054993
  l1.420517,1.4659119l3.8983917,0.4159851l2.6347961-1.757782l0.4008026,2.8700867l18.7704926,8.835907l0.2071075-0.3926086
  l0.0903015,2.5274048l8.0717926,7.4287109l-0.5590973,0.9960938l4.6981964,5.2313843l0.7144012-1.7626953l-3.3266907-8.2402039
  l-5.516098-7.4237976l-3.5483093,0.0653992l0.4849091-0.9169922l-5.2481079-3.4530945l3.844696-0.6397095l2.7862091,3.4512024
  l3.2290039-0.7059937l-0.7451019-2.2061157c0.9002991,0.9277039,1.8125,2.0566101,1.8125,2.0566101l3.1566925,1.5683899
  l-1.2987976,0.7324219l-1.0850067,2.7753906l4.2065125,4.9179993l2.1240997-2.6651001l-2.7769012-5.1795959l2.4135895,1.1982117
  l3.0835114,5.5858765l1.1859894,0.835022l-2.4471893,1.132782l2.9627991,4.2588196c0,0,2.2958984-1.2578125,3.9711914-2.233429
  l1.5240021,1.0723267l-1.940506,2.3291016l2.9805145,1.6317749l1.0883942-0.7958984l1.1493988,4.4522095l1.7158051-3.7597961
  l0.8451996,1.9306946l8.0771942,5.5917053l1.1849976-6.180603l-2.2762909-5.7626953L196.3984985,373.8486023z
   M118.7725067,349.8554077l0.2846985-0.0283203l0.2045975,0.2744141L118.7725067,349.8554077z"/>
 <polygon points="23.3604069,352.4960938 27.8545074,357.1815796 30.592308,356.1582031 30.9527073,352.7801819 
  28.5474072,350.6835938  "/>
 <polygon points="15.8833075,319.1054077 20.8140068,324.625885 23.949707,322.3320007 17.9522076,316.960907 
  12.8096075,315.8866882 12.7647076,318.7723999  "/>
 <polygon points="28.7471066,403.0116882 25.5557079,405.8241882 26.6055069,408.3016968 29.4263077,406.5 33.3799057,406.3963928 
  33.4810066,402.9911804  "/>
 <polygon points="80.5376053,385.6698914 82.2569046,389.2695007 86.4424057,389.4530945 93.5772018,384.1688843 
  90.0669022,380.1152039  "/>
 <polygon points="9.3457069,414.8710938 16.4634075,412.2138062 13.2788076,410.0350952  "/>
 <polygon points="0.0000072,416.2402039 8.2681074,412.6532898 5.4092073,412.3486023  "/>
 <polygon points="185.6459961,383.4775085 187.5557098,377.9002991 183.452713,376.9354858  "/>
 <polygon points="189.5341949,381.5282898 191.8554993,383.9237976 191.4013977,386.1943054 195.9458008,388.1416016 
  199.4786072,391.7879944 201.2324982,390.1347046 194.8809052,383.1493835  "/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Координаты в фотошопе:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/13847787/6104996

Gimp: http://www.gimp.org/downloads/ с инструкцией http://docs.gimp.org/ru/plug-in-imagemap.html

**UPD:**

Программы для работы с векторной графикой с возможностью сохранить в `svg` и посмотреть координаты тоже:

- CorelDRAW
- Adobe Illustrator CS2
- Inkscape
- SVG-Edit

Comment: Спасибо за информацию, буду разбираться

Comment: @Юрий если нужно с нуля нарисовать все фигуры, то можно воспользоваться программами, работающие с векторной графикой. Обновил ответ))) Это на будущее