# Как правильно пользоваться SVG?

Tags: svg

К примеру надо сделать кнопки :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Наверно на svg это будет лучше , или :

```
<svg width="260" height="140">
<polyline points="5,135 30,5 55,135 80,5, 105,135 130,5, 155,135 180,5, 205,135 230,5, 255,135"
          fill="none" stroke="orangered" stroke-width="5" />
```

откуда берут вот эти цифры ?:

```
5,135 30,5 55,135 80,5, 105,135 130,5, 155,135 180,5, 205,135 230,5, 255,135
```

я не знаю как правильно задать вопрос, но откуда берутся эти данные в поле polyline points ?

Нарисовал кнопку в inscape и каким образом её сделать так как на скрине ?

Строго не судите , я в svg Ноль

Comment: В фотошопе можно сделать при нарезке и  "Сохранить как web" или dreamweaver...обводите детали и сохраняете  http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/513333

Comment: Алексей это же табле получится ,  не это не вариант , надо вообще в корне изучить svg , очень часто заказывают на этой технологии

Comment: Что? кто такой "Табле"?  ......вот онлайн маппинг кстати http://www.image-maps.com/

Comment: при нарезке в фотошопе и при сохранение для web вёрстка сохранится в виде таблицы

Comment: Алексей а есть способы без он лайн ресурсов ? Ну к примеру самому ловить эти точки (в вопросе) и так  далее

Comment: Вы пример смотрели выше? Там мячи с произвольной линией. Какая таблица? Это набор координат.... **Произвольный** набор. можете хоть каля-маля сделать и вензеля... Вы их можете спокойно взять из сохраненного файла....или по-вашему вот это http://ru.crazysquirrel.ru/tools/generators/map-area/ всё таблица?))) ......... Способы есть....они как минимум в том самом примере..если нужно что-то обвести по **произвольной** ломанной линии.........Плюс векторные программы `CorelDRAW`, `Adobe Illustrator CS2`, `SVG-Edit` и рисуете в них и сохраняете как svg

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41057/discussion-between-lenovoid-and--).

Comment: Откуда берут цифры? Ну, вы же их откуда-то взяли. Полагаю, из Inkscape. Вот в нём и подобных редакторах обычно и берут. Знать о внутреннем устройстве разметки надо разве что для анимации.

Comment: ну я лично для примера взял из сети , а в инскапе у меня всё в base64 , не знаю почему так - но ... зделайте ответом _отмечу лучшим и решением

Comment: Base64? Вы в него растровую картинку запихнули, видимо?

Comment: нет , я нарисовал сразу в inscape и потом сохранил и открыл notepad++ а там не пойми что , потому я собственно и задал этот вопрос

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> откуда берут вот эти цифры ?:

Случай с `polyline points` самый простой. Тут просто задаются точки x,y.

```
polyline points="x1,y1  x2,y2  x3,y3   x4,y4 ...."
```

Пример:

```html
Пример 1:
<svg width="500" height="200" >
  <polyline points="10,10 180,10 120,100 10,100 10,10"
          fill="none" stroke="orangered" stroke-width="5" />
</svg>

Пример 2:
<svg width="500" height="200" >
  <polyline points="10,10 180,10 120,100 10,100 10,10"
          fill="#018846" stroke-width="0" />
  
  <polyline points="210,10 340,10 340,100 150,100 210,10"
          fill="#018846" stroke-width="0" />
</svg>
```

Можно использовать `path` для этих целей.

```
path = "M x,y  L x1,y1 z"
```

`M` — moveto, обозначает начало новой линии — точку, с которой мы начинаем рисовать.

`Z` — closepath — замкнуть фигуру, при этом рисуется линия от текущей точки до начальной. Действие этой команды не зависит от регистра, Z и z сработают одинаково.

`L` — lineto — рисование линии.

[Больше информации у yoksel](http://css.yoksel.ru/svg-path/)

Пример с `path`:

```html
<svg width="500" height="200">
  <path stroke="orange" fill="#018846" stroke-width="0"
        d="M 10,10 L 180,10 L 120,100 L 10,100 z"/>
  
  <path stroke="orange" fill="#018846" stroke-width="0"
        d="M 210,10 L 340,10 L 340,100 L 150,100 z"/>
</svg>
```

[И еще одна полезная статья на хабре.](https://habrahabr.ru/post/157087/)

Comment: спасибо Леночка, я уже досконально изучил SVG с момента как задал этот вопрос , вы по прежнему Лучшая в моих глазах

Comment: Будет на случай, если кому-то понадобиться)
Спасибо!

Comment: читаю свои старые вопросы иногда с моего старого акка и аж ужасаюсь -