# Как сделать такие кнопки?

Tags: html, css

Есть 4 ссылки на странице сайта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Навести и нажать можно не только на саму картинку цветную, но и на область вокруг (обведено красным). Можно ли сделать ссылку, чтобы навести и нажать можно было только на само изображение кнопки, а не на пустое пространство вокруг?

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/html/map

Comment: пример - https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/ueqgtcdh/

Comment: А как координаты определяются?

Comment: например онлайн сервис - http://imagemap-generator.dariodomi.de

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/513367/191482  тут список векторных программ, в принципе в них можно рисовать или обводить рисунок и экспортировать нужные координаты ..... DreamWeaver еще это умеет делать