# Клик по конкретному участку единой картинки и вызов модального окна

Tags: javascript, html

Есть картинка. Нужно сделать так чтобы при клике на отдельную комнату появлялось модальное окно с его реальным фото. 
Как вызвать модальное окно я знаю)) А вот как кликать по отдельному фрагменту?

Заранее спасибо за идеи и наводки! [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: покажите Ваш код

Comment: @artem55555p Не думаю, что тут нужен код. Автор просит указать на инструменты или готовые примеры, которые помогут решить данную задачу.

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/html/area/coords к примеру, а координаты получить через программы https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/513367/191482

Comment: http://imagemap-generator.dariodomi.de/

Answer (score 1):

Методов несколько, можно поставить над "комнатами" несколько `a` тегов (или других), после события `click` проверять на какую нажали и показывать модальное окно. Но думаю лучше просто получать кординаты и в коде вставить условие где будете проверять в какой диапазон кликнули

```js
function getCord(event) {
  console.log("clickX: " + event.clientX + " - clickY: " + event.clientY)
  
  }

document.getElementById('myimg').addEventListener("click", getCord);
```

```html
<img id="myimg" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9FMd.jpg">
```

Comment: Супер! Попробую, спасибо за советы! А возможно ли разделив картинку на участки с помощью этой проги  
imagemap-generator.dariodomi.de задавать им потом свойства вроде background, например?

Comment: Если честно, я не работал с данным сервисом, может @Даниил поможет ?

Comment: Друзья, на этом форуме нашла уже такую тему )) Не я первая!